# Adding Methods to a Django Model

Tags: python, django, graphql

I'm building my first GraphQL mutation.  Initially I built it using sample code I found.  But now I'm refactoring it to be better structured.  While the code seems to work fine, as I'm relatively new to Django, I'm not sure the approach I'm using is the best practice for Django/Python.

Here's my relevant code:

```html
#models.py

class Workflow(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return "{}".format(self.name)

    @classmethod
    def create(cls, name, description):
        new_workflow = cls(
            name = name,
            description = description
        )
        
        new_workflow.save()
        return new_workflow
```

```html
# mutations.py

class Workflow(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = WorkflowModel
        interfaces = (relay.Node, )

    @classmethod
    def get_node(cls, id, context, info):
        node = get_workflow(id)
        return node


class CreateWorkflow(relay.ClientIDMutation):
    class Input:
        name = graphene.String()
        description = graphene.String()

    workflow = graphene.Field(Workflow)
    success = graphene.Boolean()
    errors = graphene.String()

    @classmethod
    def mutate_and_get_payload(cls, input, context, info):
        name = input.get('name')
        description = input.get('description')

        try:
            workflow = WorkflowModel.create(name, description)
            return CreateWorkflow(workflow=workflow, success=True)

        except Exception as e:
            success = False
            return CreateWorkflow(workflow=None, success=False, errors=str(e))


class Mutation(graphene.AbstractType):
    create_workflow = CreateWorkflow.Field()
```

My primary question has to do with the way I introduced `def create` into the Django Workflow model.  Is this the proper way to do it?

Robert

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to create a "create" method into a model class in Django. You can create a new object calling its init method or using the Class.objects.create(). So you could just have:

## models.py

```
class Workflow(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return "{}".format(self.name)
```

Then to create a "workflow" you could use:

```
new_obj = Workflow(name="wf name", description="wf description")
new_obj.save()
```

Or

```
Workflow.objects.create(name="wf name",description="wf description)
```

Normally you create new classes methods or overwrite existing ones for other needs. E.g:

```
class Workflow(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    deleted = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

    @property
    def short_description(self):
        if self.description:
            return "%s..." % self.description[:20]

    # ovewriting the superclass' delete method  
    def delete(self):
        self.deleted = timezone.now()
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return "{}".format(self.name)
```